Выбрать три последних поста с исключением текущего
Как брать три последних поста не учитывая тот который открыт, для WordPress.
Я попробовал что-то типа такого, но оно у меня повторяет тот пост который открыт.
<?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'case_study',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                );

                $query = new WP_Query($args);

                if ($query->have_posts()) {
                    while ($query->have_posts()) {
                        $query->the_post();
                        ?>
<!--                        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x posts-list case__wrap">-->
                            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                    <?php get_template_part('parts/loop', 'case_study'); // Post item ?>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php starter_pagination(); ?>
<!--                        </div>-->
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                } else
                    echo '<li class="select__option">Записей нет.</li>';
                ?>


Добавить в массив как-то так
post__not_in = $post->ID;
